# Microsoft Access VBA: need to get sql representation programmatically from existing query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need to be able to get the sql "property" from an existing query.  So for example I could define `strRS` as:

```vb
 strRS = Me.RecordSource '.RecordSource returns the name of a query
```

Then pass that value to as yet undefined function `UnknownFunction(strRS)` that takes `strRS` as a value:

```vb
strSQL = UnknownFunction(strRS)
```

Then the desired output, `strSQL` would be the original SQL string that defines the query pointed to by the form's "RecordSource" property.

The closest I've been able to get is that there may be a solution using QueryDef, but that is for queries made on the fly?  What should the `UnknownFunction` be?

Once I have the strSQL string then I can extract from it to make a related query.

Comment: Why don't you check the QueryDefs collection to see what all is in it and see for yourself?

Comment: I have, and all I get are error messages from the query def object, if I were trying to make a query from scratch it would be easy. but for an existing query that was created with the query builder I can't seem to find anything that will expose any of it's properties--including its SQL definition.

Comment: Hmm. What code did you try for that?

Comment: strSS = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(Query5_TableExcerpt): which then feeds strRS into this: strRss = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(strRS).SQL?

Comment: That won't work, for two reasons: QueryDef is an object, and you have to use `Set` for object variables; you also have to supply the name as a string in the syntax you used. `Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Query5_TableExcerpt")`, for example, assuming that's the name of the query.

Comment: Yes, It also seems that I am mixing QueryDef with QueryDefs, and that is another part of my confusion. I have been trying set also and that is also throwing out errors.  I will try to get a better clip of code.  Over at the microsoft site someone claimed to have a piece of code that worked for their own purposes--I have tried it and it didn't work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it is trivial IF one doesn't make it too complicated. I probably was getting the wrong answer at first because I was confusing "QueryDefs" with "QueryDef", which I should have known.

So without further ado, the full working code is:

```vb
Function FCN_QClip(strQRY As String) As String

     qds = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(strQRY).SQL

     FCN_QClip = qds

End Function
```

`?FCN_QClip("QueryName")` will yield the desired result in the immediate window for an existing query.  Thanks to Nathan.

The solution may also be found at [Social MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3a26a941-b75b-49e4-bfe8-10c152f2b6c0/sql-or-querydef-in-vba-code?forum=accessdev).